# Facebook api permissions scope issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, permissions

I have this log in script

```
$('#getFbImg').click(function () {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                getPermissions(uid);
                getUserAlbums(uid);
                getUserUploads(uid);
            } 
            else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app
            } 
            else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                        getPermissions(uid);
                        getUserAlbums(uid);
                        getUserUploads(uid);
                    } else {
                        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                    }
                }, {scope: 'public_profile,user_photos'});
            }
        });
    });
```

which asks the user to log in in order to continue. The popup window works fine, logs in fine, but the permissions dont seem to be registered. The **very weird part** is that for my account (which is also the admin in the app) was asked for the permissions, but every other account is not.
here is a picture with the permissions object
[image]

**edit:** if I add another permission to the scope eg user birthday, my account gets asked to accept the access of the new permission, but no other account is asked for this.

**2nd edit:** i added a few other administrator accounts to check if it is because i am the administrator, and i still get the permission problem, the application does not give access to their user_photos, but it still gives to my account

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you're using the Graph API v2.0, and haven't yet had your `user_likes` and `user_photos` permissions approved for your app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

> Apps using Facebook Login that require more than public_profile
>   (default), email and user_friends will require review by Facebook in
>   order to request these permissions from people.

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review for the Review process.

Comment: does this also apply for a website using the app? because i am not using the app at all, infact there is no app, I just need the "app" for the app-id part. everything else is done with javascript

Comment: Well, somewhere you have to request the permission, even with the JavaScript SDk...

Comment: ie this line `{scope: 'public_profile,user_photos'});` ??

Comment: Yes, I'm able to read, thanks. Is the permission shown in the login dialog or not for non-admin users?

Comment: the dialog asks for permissions but not the specified from the above line, i applied for new permissions and will see in 5 to 7 days..!